# webkitEnterFullscreen() on ipad video not present?

Tags: ipad, video

I'm trying to launch a video on iPad in fullscreen on user click.

```
$('.selector').click(function(e) {
  var elem = document.getElementById("myId");
  alert(elem.getAttribute("id"));
  alert(typeof elem.webkitEnterFullscreen());
  elem.webkitEnterFullscreen();
});
```

The first alert confirms the element exists.

The second alert says undefined!

Any reason?

**Update:** Realised that for `webkitEnterFullscreen()` to work, the `video` element's meta has to be loaded. So place this inside a callback that indicates `video` is loaded